# Dumping to ABEND-AID

Tags: error-handling, cobol

I am currently writing a program that will act as a server to other application. This program will accept a request then go to the database and perform what ever function the calling application requested and return control to the calling application. In the event something goes wrong, I would like to force the program to a dump to abend-aid (for future examination) then do an `EXEC CICS RETURN` back to the calling program. I am aware that I could dump the commarea into a CICS log, but that seems... messy and wrong.

TLDR; is there a routine I can call that will do an abend-aid dump but allow the program to continue execution?

Comment: "to abend-aid" isn't accurate. All Abend-Aid is is a way to format a dump. There's a least a couple of ways to take a du... to request a storage dump without an actual abend, but 1) be aware that formatting a dump (and even producing an "unformatted" dump, which is really a formatted dump with only superficial formatting) takes time. Your users would notice. Anyway, talk it through with your CICS support people. If they're going to let you do this, they'll let you know the way they want it done. If they're not going to let you, you're not going to do it.

Comment: From what you've said so far, I would just log the detail from the requester and carry on as quick as you can. It doesn't seem to be something that most of the time a core dump would be required.

Comment: that makes sense, I'll go a head with a CICS log entry thanks bill!

Comment: Dumps can be catalogued and processed with a thing called IPCS. Your CICS staff probably will want you to stay well clear of that, since you might suck up space and then have a "Production" dump fail to be stored.  You really need to seek their advice on this.

Comment: My thought was if the database was to ever go down, we would be writing A LOT of log entries to the CICS log. I assume those logs can only hold a certain amount before the CICS region comes down? I was not aware that processing dumps would take much (if any) resources. I will talk it over with our CICS guys and see what they recommend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call CEE3ABD or CEE3AB2 or EXEC CICS DUMP TRANSACTION.  All of these are documented in the IBM Knowledge Center and are language agnostic.

I see further conversation has led to the idea of logging.  If you have an automation product you may want to talk to your systems folks about EXEC CICS WRITE OPERATOR - this is *not* something you want to just do without consulting them.  Alternatively, you can call CEEMOUT, which is similar to a COBOL DISPLAY.  Some shops are skittish about this technique, again talk to your systems folks.

Yes, if you write too many log entries you can cause a S722 abend.  Yet again, talk to the systems folks to ensure they've taken steps to ensure this doesn't happen.  Or at least becomes statistically unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the Language Environment Abend Routine, CEEABN3 if I recall correctly, and any of your abend intercept packages with capture the dump.